# How to display a Button inline within a multiline TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to embed a button "inline" within a multiline textview, like so:

[image]

I'm not sure how to do this in Android, as there are no layout elements or attributes (that I'm aware of) that allow aligning a Button where text ends in a multiline TextView. And I really don't want to use a WebView for this and do it with html / css, as this screen is already heavy enough. Any ideas how to accomplish it?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949520/android-add-internal-links-to-part-of-a-textview-that-links-to-action-in-my

Comment: @Ian D If it were only a text link then I could easily do it, however unfortunately it also has a down arrow, so has to be a button with a drawableRight.

Comment: \u2193 is a nice down-arrow

Answer (score 1):

[ClickableSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan) is the answer to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Android strings accept unicode and html characters, which includes arrows

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/en/2B63/ or https://unicode-table.com/en/1F847/ or many other variations

Comment: It doesn't work, it shows up as a square with an X in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `textview`(`tvDescription`) with the `maxLines=5` and `ellipsize=end`

I'm assuming the maximum lines you wan to show is 5

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="5"
```

Add a `view`(`btnIndicator` currently button. You can change as per your requirements) which always stays on the bottom right of the `textView`. This view contains the text (View More and View Less). Suggest you to use constraint layout which will make your task easy.

Assuming you  have got the reference to Textview as `tvDescription`.

And the view at the bottom right as `btnIndicator`. Add `onClickListener` to this view.

```
btnIndicator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int maxLines = tvDescription.getLineCount();
                if (maxLines == 5) {
                    maxLines = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    btnIndicator.setText("View Less")
                }
                else {
                    maxLines = 5;
                    btnIndicator.setText("View More")
                }
                /*
                * Here you can append the text VIEW MORE(when max lines is 5)
                * or ignore if it is already expanded
                * */
                tvDescription.setMaxLines(maxLines);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I need the button to be inline in the text, not just simply aligned to the bottom right of the textview. I don't see any capability in ConstraintLayout to achieve this.